# translation-not-found - Jhipster / angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, jhipster

I started developping with Jhipster only 1 week ago. I followed the tutorial on the site, my application run but i have a little problem. In fact, the label seems to be wrong set up, i don't find where to fix it (see the screenshot below) Someone may help  me ?

[image]

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: Which tutorial have you followed and what is the problem you're having? Find the relevant code and error messages and then ask for help.

Comment: i followed these tutorials https://jhipster.github.io/installation/ and https://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-app/  Moreover i used JDL to generate my entities connected to Sql Server (my database and tables already exists) unfortunaly, I did not see any errors in browser console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it !
You have to choose the internalization option during the generation of your project at the beginning.
Just check that there is a json file (named like your entity) in the folder WebPages/i18n/fr ou WebPages/i18n/en (in french or in english)